# Unity - How to tilt wheels?

Tags: unity-game-engine, wheelcollider

The question is - how to tilt the wheels like on the picture?

[image]

In game mode, collider rotation values ​​return to zero. Apparently the wheel collider does not support rotation. Therefore, the wheel mesh needs to be tilted. Can someone tell me how to do this?